# responsive CSS - specific css when mobile keyboard is visible?

Tags: css

Is there a way to know in `CSS` when the mobile keyboard is visible?

I've tried:

```
@media (max-height: 500px) {
    .scrollDiv {
        height: 110px !important;
    }             
}
```

But cant get it to work

Comment: what is the meaning of "keyboard is up?"

Answer (score 0):

You can't detect whether the on-screen keyboard on mobile devices is currently visible or not.

The default option is not to use a height at all. Keep you elements fluid by setting a width and possibly a `min-height`, but don't use fixed heights. That will inevitably lead to problems in responsive or fluid webdesign.